# Having trouble updating my items, image BLOB format [JAVA]

Tags: java, mysql, image, blob

the program is a shop where you can add items with photos, you can update, search, delete,add etc, i can search, delete and add but can't edit my items. it kept saying that it has a wrong sql syntax, i don't know what to do. pls help.

```
private void btn_browseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.IMAGE", "jpg", "gif", "png");
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        label_photo.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
        s = path;
        tf = "true";
    } else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("No Data");
        tf = "false";
    } else {
        tf = "false";
    }
}
```

has an error in my sql syntax, whats wrong with it?

```
public void update() {
   try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cake_ordering_system?" + "user=root&password=");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("update cake set cake_name=?,cake_description=?,cake_price=?,cake_photo=? where cake_name='" + tf_search + "'");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));

        //cake_name
        pstmt.setString(1, tf_name.getText());
        //cake_description*/
        pstmt.setString(2, ta_dc.getText());
        //cake_price
        pstmt.setString(3, tf_price.getText());
        //cake_photo
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(4, is);
        //execute the query
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully updated a new record!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to delete `)` didn't saw it.

Comment: i just rechecked my database to see if it got updated but it is still the same. Didn't receive any errors but all items, not just the image can't be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code to update images in a PostgreSQL Database.

```
        private void updateImage(int id, File tempImagem) throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempImagem);
        PreparedStatement pstm = super.operaConn.getConnDst().getConexao().prepareStatement("UPDATE table SET image = ? WHERE id = ?");

        byte[] imagemArray = new byte[(int) tempImagem.length()];
        DataInputStream imagemStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempImagem));
        imagemStream.readFully(imagemArray);
        imagemStream.close();

        pstm.setBytes(1, imagemArray);
        pstm.setInt(2, id);
        pstm.executeUpdate();
        pstm.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("ERRO no metodo updateImagem()", e);
    }
}
```

Works fine!